# Issue displaying Oracle 10g Reports generated PDFs in Google View (gview)

Tags: pdf-generation, oracleforms, google-document-viewer

I am experiencing difficulties when trying to display Oracle 10g Reports generated PDFs in Google View (gview). Crystal Reports generated PDFs open successfully using the following URL format:

https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=pdf_url

However, when I attempt to open PDFs generated by Oracle 10g Forms in gview, they fail to display. To provide more context, I have uploaded two pictures showing a comparison between the Crystal Reports generated PDF and the Oracle generated PDF.

I have attempted to download the Oracle generated PDF to a local server and then used a .NET API to display it in Google View. However, the behavior remains the same.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem when using gview with Oracle 10g Forms generated PDFs? Is there any specific formatting or configuration required for these PDFs to display correctly in gview?

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what I have tried that I downloaded both document in my server pc using .net framework then through an api endpoint I tried to preview it in google viwer same result is coming, even I changed the pdf version from 1.4 to 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first clarify something.  You are using Oracle Reports and not Oracle Forms to generate your PDF.  Also, you are using a very old version of Oracle Reports.  Likely the version generated is not supported by the Google Viewer.  You can see that Reports is generating a v1.4 PDF, whereas Crystal generates 1.7.  I have no idea if this is the issue, but it is certainly of concern as I look at it.